# Why Erase in NAND or NOR is not performed Page wise?

Tags: embedded, flash-memory

Erase is always performed by Block and never by Page or Word. If Read and Write can be performed by Page , why not Erase ?

Comment: I think its because internal architecture of the NAND and NOR, if you study architecture of NAND and NOR you would get your answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronic hardware.  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: NOR flash has no concept of a "page" - a block and a page are synonymous for NOR. NAND flash is not "random access" and must be read by *page*, and erased by *block*, for flexibility and efficiency when used as mass storage, a *block* and a *page* need not be the same size.  All this information is available [elsewhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory).

Comment: I asked this question in a bit more details and it was answered:
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125228/why-does-nand-erase-only-at-block-level-and-not-page-level

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the physical architecture of a flash device where the memory array is divided up into blocks.  It is only possible to erase the data stored in the device in blocks, either one at a time or multiple blocks in sequence or parallel (depending upon the generosity of the device manufacturer).  Just as the size of a processor word or page (whatever that may be defined as) may vary between processor architectures, the size of these blocks vary between devices - I have used devices with sectors between 32 bytes and 128K bytes.

If you need to be able to erase a single byte in the memory then you need to use EEPROM memory.